# Cannot Login to Xubuntu 18.04 though password is correct

Tags: boot, xubuntu, login

Everytime I type my password in to the login screen CORRECTLY the screen will say "started bp filter" and then go back to the login screen. Help!

Comment: Need more info. Screenshots should be helpful. Do you get black screen with text on it? You may try entering tty and take relevant logs then post here. Or you may add another user from recovery mode then logging in as another user and report if it works then we can help you. Also we need to know if the problem is system wide or specifically for your current user.

Comment: Cant really show screenshots since I'm posting via my phone,  but when I login to the GUI with my password on my account (have not tried on another account) a black screen shows and then it says "started bp filter" and then goes back to the GUI login

Comment: I think perhaps the .Xauthority file is messed up since I had to do a hard shutdown with the power button since my session froze.

Comment: When I insert `startx` I get `xauth: unable to write authority file /tmp/serverauth.g7VpZi4zqX-n ` ; `unable to write authority file /home/joe/.Xauthority-n` the semicolon represents a new line since I cant type well on my phone

Comment: I can login with `sudo startx` but not with my username

Comment: If you are getting unable to write .Xauthority make sure you have proper permission and you are the owner of the file. Login in tty Use `sudo chown username:username $HOME/.Xauthority` and see if it works. Edit: you may also need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`.